# Generator Magnet-Uri

Tags: delphi

Somebody can share algorithm of generation Magnet-Uri for file(s or dir)( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_uri )? It is desirable on Delphi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this:

http://areslite.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/helper_hashlinks.pas

Comment: Thanks, are a little not that, it not the generator, but to begin with to be useful